# Dark Energy and Newton's Gravity Formula

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, dark-energy

What would Newton's gravity formula look like if it accommodated the acceleration believed to be caused by dark energy (still assuming 2 masses)?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here.  The study of perturbed versions of Newtonian gravity using GR terms is quite common and I suspect the OP simply does not know the correct terms to use for a search.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unusual to try and add additional terms to the Newtonian expression for gravitational force to include additional effects when they are small compared to the main Newtonian term (the term normally used is *perturbation*).

However adding these terms does not properly include the effects of general relativity, so they are generally not used in this way.

The correct approach involves developing the equations of motion from the full metric and then making approximations based on the assumption of the effects being small.  This adds terms which do not relate easily to a classical force law.

This paper on Arxiv by Yurri V. Dumin explores this theoretical approach in detail : [Lambda Perturbations of Keplerian Orbits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0306)

In [a later paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01793) the same author mentions a force law modified in this way :

$$F_{eff}(r) = M_1\left( -\frac{GM_2}{r^2} + \frac{\Lambda r}{3}\right)$$

which apparently comes from something called the Kottler metric (which is not known to me but I'd cite [this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06159) for anyone interested ).  The author points out this is not a proper perturbating terms because of it's limiting properties, but it's possibly the closest thing to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Newton gravity law cannot accommodate outwards accelerating dark energy.

As it seems dark energy acceleration increases with distance while Newton gravity acceleration reduces with distance.

Comment: Gravity within a homogeneous mass distribution increases with distance just as with dark energy, though.

Comment: So its no longer Newton law

Comment: Newton's law predicts it, though. In a homogeneous distribution the mass enclosed within a sphere of radius $r$ scales as $M\propto r^3$, so Newtonian gravity predicts $F\propto M/r^2\propto r$. That's exactly the same scaling as the "force" due to homogeneous dark energy (e.g. the second Friedmann equation).